# Is the Great Tribulation equivalent to the wrath of God?

Tags: apocalyptic

> “For then there will be **great tribulation**, such as has not been from the beginning of the world until now, no, and never will be.”
> ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭24:21‬ ‭

Is this great tribulation referenced by Jesus Himself the same as God’s wrath? I ask because verses like these

> “Since, therefore, we have now been justified by his blood, much more shall **we be saved by him from the wrath of God**.”
> ‭‭Romans‬ ‭5:9‬ ‭

Or

> “and to wait for his Son from heaven, whom he raised from the dead, **Jesus who delivers us from the wrath to come**.”
> ‭‭1 Thessalonians‬ ‭1:10‬ ‭

These have OT coverage I believe in passages like

> “Come, my people, enter your chambers, and shut your doors behind you; **hide yourselves for a little while until the fury has passed by**. For behold, the Lord is coming out from his place **to punish the inhabitants of the earth for their iniquity**, and the earth will disclose the blood shed on it, and will no more cover its slain.”
> ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭26:20-21‬ ‭

This cross referenced with

> “I said to him, “Sir, you know.” And he said to me, “These are the ones coming **out of the great tribulation**. They have washed their robes and made them white in the blood of the Lamb.”
> ‭‭Revelation‬ ‭7:14‬ ‭

Begs the questions when they washed their robes? Prior, during, after?

Question remains, is this great tribulation equivalent to the wrath of God against the sinfulness of the earth? Or are they two different events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To springboard off of Levan’s answer, (which he may not appreciate :) since I may be more of a literal futurist), God did not promise to deliver us from persecution, tribulation, or even The Great Tribulation. Heaven will be full of martyrs and I don’t know why people feel this or any coming generation of Christians must be spared.

A much stronger case can be made for God sparing us from his full wrath unleashed on a rebellious unrepentant world. This hermeneutical logic may be too simple for some to accept, but the resurrection from the dead is often associated with the last trump.

> 1 Cor.15 52in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye, at the last trumpet; for
> the trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised imperishable, and
> we will be changed. NASB

Interestingly enough, there is a last trumpet mentioned in Revelation 11:

> 15Then the seventh angel sounded; and there were loud voices in
> heaven, saying, “The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of
> our Lord and of His Christ; and He will reign forever and ever.”
> 16And the twenty-four elders, who sit on their thrones before God,
> fell on their faces and worshiped God, 17saying, “We give You thanks,
> Lord God, the Almighty, the One who is and who was, because You have
> taken Your great power and have begun to reign. 18And the nations were
> enraged, and **Your wrath came**, and the time came for the dead to be
> judged, and the time to reward Your bond-servants the prophets and
> the [m]saints and those who fear Your name, the small and the great,
> and to destroy those who destroy the earth.” NASB

The sequence according to Revelation is that the dead in Christ are raised, then those who are alive and remain are caught up to meet the Lord in the air, and then the wrath comes, destroying those who have corrupted the earth. This happens with the 7 bowls of wrath being poured out on the earth in Revelation 16. The dead who were raised, along with the raptured, will reign with Christ in the millennium as described in Rev. 20.

> 5The rest of the dead did not come to life until the thousand years
> were completed. This is the first resurrection. 6Blessed and holy is
> the one who has a part in the first resurrection; over these the
> second death has no power, but they will be priests of God and of
> Christ, and will reign with Him for a thousand years.

So to answer your question, the Wrath begins after the Tribulation which ends with the resurrection and rapture. They are therefore not the same. The tribulation represents the greatest persecution the church has ever seen and Jesus said he will have to cut it short for the sake of the elect. The Great Tribulation, therefore, has much to do with the enemy's wrath toward believers. And the Wrath of God that follows, is distinguished from the wrath that God has always reserved for the disobedient and rebellious.

> Ro 1 18 The wrath of God is being revealed from heaven against all the
> godlessness and wickedness of men who suppress the truth by their
> wickedness. BSB

I believe Jesus literally fulfilled OT prophecy with his first coming and that he will literally fulfill OT and NT prophecy with his second coming. I usually don’t get into heated debates with people about it. I just say, “Time will tell.” I have a feeling, though, that time may be telling soon. Besides, isn’t that what Jesus said?

> Rev. 22:12 “Behold, I am coming soon, and My reward is with Me, to
> give to each one according to what he has done. BSB

Answer (score 2):

The two terms, tribulation and wrath of God, should be separated: tribulation is a temporary phenomenon, like persecutions, famines, illnesses, earthquakes, suffering of treason of close people, which is the greatest of all tribulations, but wrath of God is eternal thing, in sense that has to do with eternal feature of God, who continuously and unfailingly loves all, even the worst of sinners, even Satan himself.

Now, if we shall not become like Him through His Son the Lord Jesus Christ and be His children through the Lord's grace (John 1:12), through co-crucifying of our old man on cross with Christ (Romans 6:6), so that, as Paul says, not we, but He may live in us (Galatians 2:20), then the divine eternity where there is a great separation of His Kingdom from hell (for there will be no middle: either the Kingdom or its outside - hell), will be eternal, unending torment for us (Matthew 25:46), which torment is called "wrath of God", but metaphorically and even ironically, for in fact this "wrath" is not His emotion of anger or such a stupid crude anthropomorphism, but our inability to accept Him as He is - the eternal and unwavering Lover of all His creatures.